# Mailto: inside php and html table

Tags: php, html, mailto

I'm populating an html table with data from MySQL DB and I want to add a `mailto` function on the click of one of the columns. Problem is **when I do it, the column is blank, but when I inspect it in the browser it shows up in the inspect panel.**

My Code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Property_ID']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['House_Number']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Street_Address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Postal_Code']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['City']."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."<a href='mailto:".$row['Submitted_By']."'></a>"."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Date_Submitted']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
```

What the browser shows:

[image: What the browser shows]

On inspection:

[image: On inspection]

Comment: Please stop using blockquote for text. I edited 2-3 of your other posts. This matter has been discussed on meta. Repeating actions like this, are flaggable for moderation.

Comment: So I ended up editing this one also; you could have done that, really.

Comment: sorry I'd seen a few people do the same so I didn't think it was a big deal

Comment: well, they eventually get caught. If someone threw themselves off a beautiful bridge, would you jump also? ...... I didn't think so; least I hope not ;-) and it is a big deal, it's not meant for text, it's meant to either highlight an error, or to quote something from a manual or other site where information gets pulled from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `<a>` tag is empty, that's why you don't see your link.

You have to add your text inside `<a>` and `</a>`:

```
echo "<td>"
   . "<a href='mailto:".$row['Submitted_By']."'>".$row['Submitted_By']."</a>"
   . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td>"."<a href='mailto:".$row['Submitted_By']."'>".$row['Submitted_By']."</a>"."</td>";
```

this line should be exactly like this.